# How to avoid "RuntimeError: error in LoadLibraryA" for torch.cat?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch

I am running a  [pytorch solution for wireframe detection](https://github.com/huangkuns/wireframe). I am receiving a "RuntimeError: error in LoadLibraryA" when the solution executes "forward return torch.cat(outputs, 1)"

I am not able to provide a minimal re-producable example. Therefore the quesion: Is it possible to produce just type of error in a microsoft library by python programming errors, or is this most likely a version (of python, pytorch, CUDA,...) problem or a bug in my installation?

I am using windows 10, python 3.8.1 and pytorch 1.4.0.

```
File "main.py", line 144, in <module>
  main()
File "main.py", line 137, in main
  trainer.train(train_loader, val_loader=None)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Projects\wireframe\wireframe\junc\trainer\balance_junction_trainer.py", line 75, in train
  self.step(epoch, train_loader)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Projects\wireframe\wireframe\junc\trainer\balance_junction_trainer.py", line 176, in step
  ) = self.model(input_var, junc_conf, junc_res, bin_conf, bin_res)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Environment\Environments\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
  result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Projects\wireframe\wireframe\junc\model\inception.py", line 41, in forward
  base_feat = self.base_net(im_data)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Environment\Environments\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
  result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Projects\wireframe\wireframe\junc\model\networks\inception_v2.py", line 63, in forward
  x = self.Mixed_3b(x)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Environment\Environments\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
  result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dev\Python\Projects\wireframe\wireframe\junc\model\networks\inception_v2.py", line 97, in forward
  return torch.cat(outputs, 1)
RuntimeError: error in LoadLibraryA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this workground: run the following code after import torch (should be fixed in 1.5):

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('caffe2_nvrtc.dll')
```

Comment: Is there a github issue tracking this?

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to avoid this error by downgrading to python 3.7.6

Remark: Unfortunately, the first step of the overall processing (run time 3 days on my GPU) creates intermediate results with pickel format 5, which is new in Python 3.8. Therefore, I either have to re-run the first step for 3 days or find another solution. The files with the intermediate results cannot be used with python 3.7.6